# pandas join data frames on similar but not identical string using lower case only

Tags: python, pandas

I need to join data frames on columns that are similar but not identical. Fortunately, the lowercase letters are identical between columns. So I am trying to isolate the lowercase letters from each column, create new columns to join on.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': ['1', '2', '3'],
               'beta': ['JRLeparoux', 'BJHernandez,Jr.','SXBridgmohan'],})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': ['1', '2', '3'],
               'gamma': ['Leparoux R', 'Hernandez,B, Jr.','Bridgmohan S X'],
               'zeta': ['17', '23','116'],})
```

This is what I have tried

```
def joinnames(df):    
    filelist = []
    for c in df:
        if c.islower():
             filelist.append(c)
    return filelist

df1['joinhere'] = df1['beta'].apply(joinnames) 
df2['joinhere'] = df2['gamma'].apply(joinnames)
pd.merge(df1,df2, how ='left', left_on = 'joinhere', right_on = 'joinhere' )
```

This is the output that I am trying to achieve.

```
final = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': ['1', '2', '3'],
               'gamma': ['Leparoux R', 'Hernandez,B, Jr.','Bridgmohan S X'],
               'beta': ['JRLeparoux', 'BJHernandez,Jr.','SXBridgmohan'],
               'zeta': ['17', '23','116'],})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) to find the lowercase letters:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': ['1', '2', '3'],
               'beta': ['JRLeparoux', 'BJHernandez,Jr.','SXBridgmohan'],})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': ['1', '2', '3'],
               'gamma': ['Leparoux R', 'Hernandez,B, Jr.','Bridgmohan S X'],
               'zeta': ['17', '23','116'],}) 


df1['lower'] = df1['beta'].str.extract(r'([a-z]+)')
df2['lower'] = df2['gamma'].str.extract(r'([a-z]+)')
final = pd.merge(df1, df2)
print(final)
```

yields

```
  alpha             beta      lower             gamma zeta
0     1       JRLeparoux    eparoux        Leparoux R   17
1     2  BJHernandez,Jr.   ernandez  Hernandez,B, Jr.   23
2     3     SXBridgmohan  ridgmohan    Bridgmohan S X  116
```

Note that this assumes collecting all ASCII characters from `a` to `z` suffices to produce values on which to join.
If your `beta` and `gamma` columns contains non-ASCII lowercase characters (such as characters with accent marks) then you may need to add those to the regex character class, `[a-z]`.